# sql lookup ID and insert if no result found

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-functions

I have a select statement that needs to look up a customer `ID` from a customer name. If an `ID` does not exist for that name, a new record needs to be created in the customer table. this has to be done as part of a select statement (related to the app its being run from).

I tried looking at a UDF that returned either the existing `ID` or a new `ID`, before realizing that you can't modify tables from a function.

any idea how to accomplish this?

EDIT:

I think i need to clarify things a bit more. The select statement can and will change on a per-implementation basis. What I'm looking for is a generic way of looking up or creating the customer id (that table and the need to do the lookup does not change) as part of a larger select statement.

the app that is using the sql loads the select statement from a config file, and has `'SELECT'` hard coded, so there's no chance of adding an exec before the select etc.

It looks like what I need is something like `'select a.1 (exec dotheLookup(name)) as customerID, a.2 FROM table`, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Comment: What db are you using?

Comment: oops. SQL express 2008 r2

Comment: Use store procedure instade of function.

Comment: You want select statement in function or Stored procedure?

Comment: how do you use a stored proc as part of a select statement? it needs to end up like 'select a.1, a.2, lookup(customerName) as customerID from table' the whole thing must be in one select statement (bad app design that I'm having to compensate for)

Comment: I can't think of a way to perform a data manipulation for a single query that starts with a `SELECT` keyword.

Comment: yeah thats the problem I had. I've updated the question, hopefully that will help clarify the problem.

Comment: The only objects that can appear as part of a `SELECT` statement are tables, views and UDFs. Tables are out. Views are essentially just a macro of another `SELECT`. And UDFs aren't allowed to modify the database; it appears to be banned even for CLR-UDFs - although it *may* be possible to open a completely new connection to the database from within a CLR-UDF and do it that way - but is a CLR-UDF even allowed?

Comment: You cannot modify records in any way with just a select.

Comment: Can you modify the database in any way?

Comment: Also, can you clarify how if the statement is in a CONFIG file you are able to pass the query string to the app? is it "SELECT" + your string?

Comment: yep thats how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to Create a stored procedure for this. Something like

```
Create procedure customer
--parameters
AS
Begin
IF exists(Select lookup(customerName) as customerID from table)
  BEGIN
    --Your select goes here
  END 
ELSE
  BEGIN
   --Insert into customer table and return scopeidentity
   --Select goes here
  END

END
```

Updated Answer:

You cannot perform data manipulation using select statement.

Comment: the statement could include sub queries etc. it just must begin with 'SELECT'

Answer (score 0):

You could execute a stored procedure before you execute the SELECT statement, the run a function that returns ID from name:

```
exec CheckForCustomerByNameAndAddIDIfItDoesntExist(customerName)
declare iCustomerID int
select iCustomerID = GetCustomerIDFromName(customerName)
select a.1, a.2, iCustomerID  as customerID from table
```

Something like that

Comment: unfortunately i cant run anything before the select statement. the app thats using the query loads it from a config file and executes it as is. it also has 'select' hard coded. fail design is fail but its what i'm stuck with.

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify the database server? If so, add a linked server pointing to the local server.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LinkedLocal', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc=N'LocalServerName'
 EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'LinkedLocal',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
```

Then just run an OPENQUERY that invokes a stored procedure that does your work:

```
select * from OPENQUERY("LinkedLocal", 'exec Database.Schema.StoredProcedure ''Param1'', ''Param2'')
```

Comment: its a possibility, I'll have to check on that one!